# iPhone 6 screen touch highlights but doesn't activate controls

Tags: iphone, ios

Often, when I touch an iPhone 6 screen control the control highlights, recognizing that it's been touched, but the control doesn't activate to perform its intended function.

Is this an intended mimic of 3D touch?

Is this a feature of iOS (9.3.2), or of the running app?

When it happens I have to touch the control longer for it to take effect.

Comment: Do you have any Accessibility settings on?

Comment: Zoom (Follow focus, smart typing, window zoom), reduce motion, vibration, phone noise cancellation. Any of these interfering?